# Almost sure divergence of sum of squares of independent standard Gaussians

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

How does one show $\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k^2 = \infty$ almost surely, where $X_k$ are i.i.d $N(0,1)$?

My first thought is that $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{k=1}^K X_k^2] = \sum_{k=1}^K \mathbb{E}[X_k^2]$ diverges, but I don't think $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\infty$ implies $\mathbb{P}(Y=\infty)=1$, or does it?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, $E[Y]=\infty$ does not imply $P(Y=\infty)=1$. For a counterexample, let $Y$ have value $2^k$ with probability $2^{-k}$ ($k=1,2,\ldots$); then $E[Y]=\infty$ while $P(Y=\infty)=0$.

To show your result, a hint: Apply the second Borel-Cantelli lemma: If $Y_1, Y_2,\ldots,$ are independent and $\sum_i P(Y_i>c)=\infty$ for some $c$, then the probability is $1$ that $Y_n>c$ infinitely often. Your job is to find suitable $Y_i$ and $c$.